# Не работает ссылка на сайт в результатах поиска в яндексе

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, яндекс-поиск

https://yandex.ru/search/?text=DONWATCH&ncrnd=9763&lr=39

При поиске , когда переходишь по ссылке "Сайт" (right-up на правом углу поиска) , не удается получить доступ к сайту, в чем может быть причина ?как исправить данную проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день! Измените вашу ссылку https://www.donwatch.ru/ на http://www.donwatch.ru/

В Яндекс.Вебмастер нужно поменять https на http. Пардон, в Яндекс.Справочник в данном случаи.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все работает !!!